# Nagios 3.2.3 Core web interface login via LDAP using full names for username

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, authentication, login

First off I've never done any Nagios or LDAP configuration in the past and I've been sort of dumped into this as is so often the case so forgive my inevitable ignorance regarding these things but I've been digging for a while all over the place in regards to this issue and I'm fairly firmly stuck right now.

When I go to the URL to pull up the Nagios Core terminal and it prompts me to log in the current configuration I have does check against LDAP as I want it to but the username is authenticating against the user's full name (Distinguished Name?). For example, if I'm a user named John Doe I would be able to log in with the following credentials:

Username: 'John Doe'
Password:

It's obviously not ideal to have a fully written out name, complete with caps and spaces, as the username. Elsewhere in the system LDAP does authenticate against a standardized username. In John Doe's case this would be 'jdoe'. I need this behavior here in the Nagios login.

I think I've chased down the config file on the responsible server (which runs Linux 2.6.18-308.13.1.el5, CentOS release 5.8 (Final)). It's /etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf. This is part of the anonymized contents of that file, anything in <>s is actually in there and works fine besides the aforementioned issue:

```
#  SSLRequireSSL
   Options ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
#  Order deny,allow
#  Deny from all
#  Allow from 127.0.0.1
#   AuthName "Nagios Access"
#   AuthType Basic
#   AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
#   Require valid-user
AuthType Basic
AuthName "SST/Nagios"
AuthzLDAPMethod          ldap
AuthzLDAPProtocolVersion 3
AuthzLDAPServer          <IP:Port>
AuthzLDAPUserBase        cn=Users,dc=<domain>,dc=com
AuthzLDAPUserKey         CN
AuthzLDAPBindDN cn=ldapanon,cn=users,dc=<domain>,dc=com
AuthzLDAPBindPassword "<herebeapassword>"
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

I'm also pretty sure that it has something to do with the AuthzLDAPUserKey and the value coming in for CN but I'm having trouble pinning down what the alternative values either in the Base, Key, or BindDN lines would make it authenticate off of the username (jdoe) rather than the person's full name (John Doe). Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What ldap server?  Is this AD, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, It is AD.

Comment: Try changing your `AuthzLDAPUserKey` to `sAMAccountName`.

Comment: I just tried this. With these settings neither John Doe nor jdoe work. Looking around though I do see what you mean, that seems like a logical choice and it seems like the Key value is what needs to change.